# Eclipse: Use Aptana theme for Javascript editor only?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, editor, themes, aptana

When I use Aptana in Eclipse, I like the Cobalt theme for my Javascript.  However, this theme ends up making my SVN diff-ing nearly impossible for my Java files, because the background is dark blue, and the text is black in the compare editor.

I've look all over the preferences in Eclipse, and can't figure out a way to only use the Aptana Cobalt theme for editing my Javascript files.

Here are the things I've tried:
 - I've made the Aptana JavaScript editor the default for "*.js" files
 - I've made the default for ".txt" and "*.java" the normal editors (non-Aptana, whatever they are)
 - I've tried setting the theme, and making sure that General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts still has all the defaults
 - I've verified that if I changed the theme to something with a white background, my diff-ing editor gets changed and becomes readable

What else can I do?!  I just want to use Aptana for Javascript, not my default diff theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to achieve this.  I would suggest to create a JIRA ticket at http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to their JIRA.  Created issue here: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3492

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. No idea wether it has been resolved yet, but I found a temporary solution which might help. I changed the default editor for Javascript in Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations. When you select ".js" from the upper list, you'll see all the possible editors in the bottom list. I made "Javascript Source Editor" my default editor. This editor uses the default theme settings.